# Avro 1.9.1 Logical Type "uuid" maps to String type in java class

Tags: java, uuid, avro

Schema field definition is as,

```
{
        "name": "uuid",
        "type": {
          "type": "string",
          "logicalType": "uuid"
        }
      }
```

After avro maven compilation it generates String type for uuid logical type.

```
@Deprecated public java.lang.String uuid;
```

It should be of type UUID. Can someone please help here? How I will get UUID object directly?

Answer (score 0):

> UUID uid = UUID.fromString(value);

When you are getting name value it will take value as string and then you can format that string value to UUID.

Hope this will work

Comment: Yes, that is how I have done but that's not clean way. It should give UUID object directly.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I was wondering where the logical type mappings may be documented. The below seems to support youre requirement, but I don't have a worked example to share:
https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/api/java/org/apache/avro/Conversions.UUIDConversion.html